# PHP-based indexing and search implementation

Tags: php

Is there such thing?

I designed a while back a rudimentary form based app for my users.

We receive from our suppliers hardware manufacturing data in XML files: file name is made of eleven fields separated by tildes, with each field having its own meaning.

R&D guys wanted to be able to search each field of the file names so I used regex() with decent results.

Problem is that we have now in the upwards of 2.5 million files. And my app can't hack it anymore.

I looked at Apache Lucene & Solr. Though it seemed like the best solution to my problem, the fields in the filenames are not peers to the file content. Big no-no with Solr.

What is the best way to implement a PHP app with indexing and search capability with such large number of files?

Do I have to buy Zend and use Zend_Search? Is it the only way?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm assuming something like MySQL's FULLTEXT search is not an option?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a newbie and did not know a darn thing about  MySQL's FULLTEXT capability. This is actually what I am working on at the moment.

Comment: Does this not belong on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive xml files from suppliers, **put the information in a database**.  Thats what they are designed for.  You'll have essentially instantaneous searches.  If the fields are consistent, a regular old SQL database will do the trick.  If each is different, perhaps look at a NoSQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always [Xapian](http://xapian.org/features), or more specifically [Omega](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html). You can integrate it through cgi, and then be able to have lightning-fast indexing and searching of different web server documents.

In this case, you might want to have a look at their guide for **[how to add support for XML files](http://trac.xapian.org/wiki/FAQ/OmegaNewFileFormat)**.